# How to get part of a list in return values

Tags: python

I'd like to return several values in a method, including a list.

Following works fine:

```
def foo():
  a = 42
  b = [1,2]
  return a, b

aa, b_list = foo()      
aa, (b1, b2) = foo()
```

But I don't know how get a list without first element:

```
def bar():
  a = 42
  b = [1,2,3]
  return a, b

aa, (_, b_list) = bar()
print(b_list)  # Expecting [2,3]
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Yes I can get the list and drop first element, but is there a one-liner for this?

This function is supposed be versatile, for example should be supporting two scenarios:

```
aa, whole_list = foo()
aa, first_elem, rest_of_the_list = foo()
```

Comment: This seems more about how to unpack a function.  Look into tuple unpacking, with start.  Ex: `aa, lst = foo()` or `aa, (first, *rest) = foo()` should work in Python 3.

Comment: @pylang just tested that `aa, first, *rest = foo()` is not working, need to add `()`

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use unpacking for `b_list`:

```
aa, (_, *b_list) = bar()
```

- Note this works only in python 3.

Comment: @helloV I can confirm this works in Python v3.5.2 on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `list slice`; you can return a contiguous range of the list, such as

```
return a, b[1:]
```

This notation gives you elements 1 through the end -- everything but the first element.

If you need to drop the first item after the return, just use the same syntax:

```
print(b_list[1:])
```

or permanently alter (until the next assignment) `b_list` with

```
b_list = b_list[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be working. Updated my question.

Comment: The question is how to process the return values not how to alter the return values.

Comment: @Uriel I should have clarified my question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a one liner, but I'd try using a namedtuple to make the nature of the retval clearer

```
from collections import namedtuple
retval = namedtuple('retval', 'scalar list')

def bar():
  a = 42
  b = [1,2,3]
  return retval(a, b)

rv = bar()
a, b = rv.scalar, rv.list[1:]
```

Answer (score -1):

so from what i understand you want to get a back which is 42 and be back which is 1,2,3

i would try

```
def bar():
  a = 42
  b = [1,2,3]
  return a, b

a, b = bar()
print(b)  # Expecting [2,3]
print(aa)
```